# Using scss and the asset pipeline in a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sass, sinatra, assets

I was wondering how i get Sass and the asset pipeline to work in my Sinatra app, from what i have read it is loaded quicker than CSS and I can compress my files upon precompile and cache my assets? Plus i would like to be able to have one application.scss stylesheet and @import all my other stylesheets

I'm used to using Rails a bit so am a little spoilt in the fact that everything is done for you configuration wise.

I want to improve the performance of rendering my assets and at the moment all i can think of doing is minifying my js and css and then pushing that to my server

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sinatra Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline). It’s a gem that implements a Rails-like asset preprocessing engine using Sprockets.

I usually use Grunt to handle the assets when working with Sinatra. I have a Grunt task that watches for file changes in `/assets/` and then compiles the files to `/public/` where they’re accessible to the Sinatra app. Also I exclude the compiled files in `/public/` from version control to only have the source in there. I found Grunt to give me a little more freedom and it allows for more complex configuration options.

For caching it depends a little more on the server setup and whether you can set the right `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers for the css files.